# Pandas: Retrieving an Index from a dataframe to populate another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to find a solution to this but have failed

I have my master df with transactional data and specifically credit card names:

```
transactionId, amount, type, person
1              -30     Visa  john
2              -100    Visa Premium john
3              -12     Mastercard jenny
```

I am grouping by person and then aggregating by numb of records and amount.

```
person   numbTrans   Amount
john     2           -130
jenny    1           -12
```

This is fine but I need to add the dimension of creditcard type to my df.
I have grouped a df of the creditcards in use

```
index    CreditCardName
0        Visa
1        Visa Premium
2        Mastercard
```

So, what I can't do is creating a new column in my master dataframe called 'CreditCard_id' which uses the string 'Visa/Visa Premium/Mastercard' to pull in the index for the column.

```
transactionId, amount, type, CreditCardId, person
1              -30     Visa  0             john
2              -100    Visa Premium 1      john
3              -12     Mastercard 2        jenny
```

I need this as I am doing some simple kmeans clustering and require ints, not strings (or at least I think I do)

Thanks in advance

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the 'CreditCardName' as the index of the second df then you can just call `map`:

```
In [80]:
# setup dummydata
import pandas as pd

temp = """transactionId,amount,type,person
1,-30,Visa,john
2,-100,Visa Premium,john
3,-12,Mastercard,jenny"""

temp1 = """index,CreditCardName
0,Visa
1,Visa Premium
2,Mastercard"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
# crucually set the index column to be the credit card name 
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), index_col=[1])
df
Out[80]:
   transactionId  amount          type person
0              1     -30          Visa   john
1              2    -100  Visa Premium   john
2              3     -12    Mastercard  jenny
In [81]:

df1
Out[81]:
                index
CreditCardName       
Visa                0
Visa Premium        1
Mastercard          2

In [82]:
# now we can call map passing the series, naturally the map will align on index and return the index value for our new column
df['CreditCardId'] = df['type'].map(df1['index'])
df
Out[82]:
   transactionId  amount          type person  CreditCardId
0              1     -30          Visa   john             0
1              2    -100  Visa Premium   john             1
2              3     -12    Mastercard  jenny             2
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp)) fails with 'TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str'

Comment: That's my code just to recreate your df, you're not supposed to use it to create your df.

Comment: In your code you should set the index on your second df to 'CreditCardName' using `df.set_index('CreditCardName',inplace=True)`

Comment: Great, was just trying to run your code to get a feel for it before moving to mine.
Thanks. Works!!